# website using url-rewriting does not load in Chrome!

Tags: url-rewriting, google-chrome

I have a PHP page called contact.php, and a rewrite rule in .htaccess
`RewriteRule ^(.*).html  $1\.php [L]` that gives contact.php when asked for contact.html.

All the pages works (on Firefox and IE), but when I enter on the site with Chrome it loads only the index page and the others don't work at all - I receive a 404 error.

I don't think is a server issue (I'm using Ubuntu server 8.04) I think is a browser issue but still unexplainable...

Has sombody a clue to follow?

Comment: Hey! the problem had somehow solved, after a few minutes. I'm not sure but it seems to be related with some cache - of the browser or Google's cache.

Comment: I've been having this experience with Google Chrome, as I work on rewrite rules. It seems to cache even the redirect/rewrite responses (and doesn't seem to clear them, even when clearing history), so when I update the rules, Chrome doesn't follow. I've learned to change the test url when working on the rules (append 2, 3, etc.). This is only anecdotal, but it feels like it eventually times out, and then works.